# Serializing a class member in protobuf

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have following class:

```
public class A
{
    public Options Options 
    {
        get { return mOptions; }
        set { mOptions = new Options(value); }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to encrypt the value of `Options` (first encode it to base64 then encrypt it) before serialization process? 
However I don't want to change the access modifier of the `Options` member.

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: well I am not familiar of a way encrypt an attribute directly, you can instead have Encrypt and Decrypt that which you can use to serialize and deserialize accordingly

Comment: @VinayPandey but how would I convert the class options to base64 then ? it must be serialized.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair instead of posting the regular question what have you tried, it would better to suggest a way if you know something about the mentioned problem. it's obvious.

Comment: @andre ... from http://stackoverflow.com/tour "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about **what you have tried** and exactly what you are trying to do."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protobuf.Net can handle before/after serialization/deserialization callbacks.
You can use them to change or initialize your fields.

For example, you can use the following code to do what you need:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class A
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private string m_OptionsEncrypted;

    private Options mOptions;

    public Options Options 
    {
        get { return mOptions; }
        set { mOptions = new Options(value); }
    }

    [ProtoBeforeSerialization]
    private void OnSerializing()
    {
        m_OptionsEncrypted = Encrypt(mOptions);
    }

    [ProtoAfterDeserialization]
    private void OnDeserialized()
    {
        mOptions = Decrypt(m_OptionsEncrypted);
    }
};
```

Please note, that `mOptions` field does not have `ProtoMember` attribute. This allows us to serialize/deserialize only `m_OptionsEncrypted` field and convert it to `Options` class in corresponding callbacks.

Comment: what if m_Options is not a string, it's just a class.. which has few members. Is it possible to get the serialized class then encrypt it ? using the callback ?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. In `Encrypt` method you can serialize `m_Options` to `Stream` and then encrypt and encode it to base64 string.

Comment: is it possible to explicitly call one of the callbacks like [ProtoBeforeSerialization] ? from any other classes ?

Comment: @andre, These callbacks are regular functions. You can make them `public` and call them when you need.